# Getting client data fast

Tags: c++, winsock, ssl, iocp

Is there a better method (using Windows) for getting a moderate amount of data from many clients quickly without using select (but I am willing to use select if need be).  IOCP is no good to me and ippoll is for Linux.  This has to be compatible with OpenSSL because I am running TLS.  for some reason BIO objects don't work on my machine (Windows 7) they just don't.  So, I piggy-backed the encryption onto winsock connections (that worked).  Your responce is appreciated.

Comment: Strange that BIO objects don't work, did you try the sample code I have for using OpenSSL with async socket methods on windows?http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/using-openssl-with-asynchronous-sockets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why select() would be significantly quicker, or slower, than any other method, including blocking-mode I/O, async I/O, etc, unless you are handling very large numbers of connections. You can't get any data until it arrives and has been decrypted. Possibly your problem is at the sending end?